# Convert a string format hexadecimal number to 0xFFFFF format wchart_t type in C

Tags: c, hex, emoji

I have a C programming problem where the user enters a hexadecimal number in string type. The program is supposed to convert it to wchart_t type.

Example:

- User enters a string: 0x4A33F
- Then, the program converts that string into wchart_t and prints out corresponding emoji.

I need help on converting that string into wchart_t.

Comment: Another Example: User Enters --> "0x1F601" ; then, program outputs a smily face

Comment: [Convert hex string (char \[\]) to int?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10156409)

Comment: Check out `strtol`. This will convert a string of characters to a number from a particular base. You can then store these converted values into your `wchar_t` array.

Comment: I heard about strtol. But I was confused on how to use it.

Comment: Once you have the `wchar_t` value(s), you can convert them to multibyte sequences (typically UTF-8) for output by calling `wctomb()` or `wcstombs()`.  (Note that you'll typically have to call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` first.)

Comment: `0xFFFFF` may be outside the range of `wchart_t`.  It is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    long code;
    fgets(line, MAXLINE, stdin);

    if (line && sscanf(line, "%x", &code)) {
        printf("%c", code);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1; /* error */
}
```

Comment: I'd expect `"%lx"` with `long code`.  `printf("%c", code);` is a type mis-match.